# How do Continuationists discern between genuine and made-up interpretations of tongues?

Tags: spiritual-gifts, charismatic, speaking-in-tongues, discernment, continuationism

When someone claiming to have the gift of interpretation of tongues interprets someone else's tongue speaking, how do Continuationists (e.g. Pentecostals, Charismatics, etc.) go about determining whether the interpretation is genuine or made-up? How do they tell whether someone's tongues are genuine and someone else's interpretation is also genuine? What is the biblical basis for their "discernment procedure", if any?

Comment: Are you asking how one would know if someone else is telling a lie ? It is often very obvious when someone tells lies.

Answer (score 1):

My godmother spent a lot of time in Charismatic churches. She said that anyone who made themselves the center of attention every week was faking it. That's not based on a Biblical passage but it's remarkably useful.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  We're different to a lot of other sites so please take our Tour to find out what we look for in well-researched answers: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour